# CS0118: "variable" is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, instance

I have 2 cs files one named Heading and one named Accounts.  There is a class in the Heading file named Heading and I want to use some of the methods in there in the Accounts cs file.  I went to create an instance:

```
Heading heading = new Heading();
```

Then when I use the heading I don't have access to the Heading methods and I get the Error in the title. However I can use

```
Heading.GetThis();
```

I'm trying to find out why sometime I have to create an instance of another cs file and sometime I have to call the cs file class directly as I have in the same project another cs file called AccountName and there I had to create the instance

```
AccountName accountName = new AccountName();
```

Then I had uses of all the AccountNames methods.

Sorry if this didn't make since I tried to google this error but didn't see a solution for what i'm looking at.

Comment: Sometimes you made a method `static` and sometimes you didn't. If you want the methods to be available on instances, remove `static`.

Comment: You should show the two classes

Comment: We can only speculate as to what the code is inside the classes.  But possibly they aren't public methods?

Comment: Sorry I should have posted my classes but Thomas Weller that is exactly what it was.  Once I changed them from static I was able to see them in my Account.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer given in comments:

```
public class Heading
    {
        private Heading()
        {

        }
        public static Heading GetThis()
        {
            return new Heading();
        }
    }
```

Code above creates the condition you explained. The `Heading.cs` is hiding its constructor to force its users to instantiate it in a specific way. There is a good chance that your Heading.cs is using singleton design pattern. If that is the case there should be a good reason for it.
[This youtube video discusses what is singleton](https://youtu.be/NZaXM67fxbs)

**Alternatives :** use Heading.cs as intended by the its designer `Heading heading = Heading.GetThis();`. Or modify Heading.cs to

```
//make constructor public 
        public Heading()
        {
        }
```

Comment: The answer was already given in the comments, and it wasn't this.